# Duplicate edges in .gml file using networkx.read_gml python

Tags: python, networkx, gml-geographic-markup-lan

I want to use networkx in python to read a .gml file.

However when I do,

```
import networkx as nx
nx.read_gml("myfilename.gml")
```

it raises the error

```
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: edge #213 (103->400) is duplicated
```

which is true that in the .gml file there are duplicate edges.

Is there any way to read a .gml file with duplicate edges without raising an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply add "multigraph 1" to the file header, which allows the graph to have multiple edges and will result in `nx.read_gml` returning a `MultiDiGraph`.

Already, the full error trace should already give you this answer

```
Hint: If multigraph add "multigraph 1" to file header.
```

taken from [`parse_gml_lines`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/readwrite/gml.html), if you are using the latest `networkx` version.